# Is there a better way to run a JavaScript several times on one html page?

Tags: javascript

The script is:

```
<code>
  <script>
  // set up the base pattern
  var pattern = Trianglify({
    height:210,
    width: 360,
x_colors:'random',
    cell_size: 20 })
  // svg
  document.getElementById("img").appendChild(pattern.svg())
// select the div (or someting) to generate a svg image.
  </script>
</code>
```

A plugin called "trianglify" (https://github.com/qrohlf/trianglify).

The problem is, I have several divs to select and fill up, but when this script run, it only generate one random code for all, so the result will be the same for all divs.

The normal and silly way came to my mind is copy this script to each every place where it needs a result, but it seems not cool and not clean.

Is there a better way to get several different random patterns in this situation?

Like came across a little script -> load the main script to generate -> next little script.... how to make that happen in js?

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: the obvious thing would be to put this code into a loop. Make it loop through all the divs you want to populate - i.e. you would select them from the DOM, loop through them, and for each one you'd run this code to populate that div.

Comment: You probably used the same `id` "img" for all your divs which causes the script to append to all of them. Also, using the same `id` on multiple elements is not advisable in HTML. You should use an event listener instead and append the svg to the img element that was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build a function that takes in the configurable items and then run that whenever you want to. This will save code repetition.

```
function RunTriangle(height, width, colors, cellSize, element) {
      var pattern = Trianglify({
          height:height,
          width: width,
          x_colors:colors,
          cell_size: cellSize
      })

      document.getElementById(element).appendChild(pattern.svg())
}
```

And then call this like so (I'm using the original data here):

`RunTriangle(210, 360, 'random', 20, 'img');`

If you want to run this a load of times, make a `Dictionary` of all the items as `objects` and then iterate through it, calling this method with the object properties.

```
const triangles = {
    first: {
        height: 100,
        width: 20,
        colors: 'random',
        cellSize: 10,
        element: 'anotherElement'
    },
    // repeat this however many times you want
};
```

Then you can use this like:

```
const configurableTriangles = Object.keys(triangles);

for(let key in configurableTriangles) {
    const current = triangles[key];
    RunTriangle(current.height, current.width, current.colors, current.cellSize, current.element
}
```

This will take every configured `Triangle` from your object and then run it against whatever you're doing.

Comment: Not a problem :)

Comment: Also make sure you use the updated `for loop` at the bottom of the question. I originally put in broken code and updated it a few minutes later to the correct version :)

Answer (score 2):

You can select all element you want to fill up and use a loop to generate new svg and append to each element.

`js-tri-fill` is the class name for each div.

```
 var divsList = document.querySelectorAll('.js-tri-fill');
 divsList.forEach(function(ele, index) {
    var pattern = Trianglify({
        height:210,
        width: 360,
        x_colors:'random',
        cell_size: 20 });
    ele.appendChild(pattern.svg())
})
```

Comment: Thank you DarknessZX, I've tried your code and it worked perfectly! Thank you very much.